# "No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document"

Tags: android, xml, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to code a softkeyboard for 2.1 and up when I code ( see code below) in the main.xml graphical view is displays nothing and says No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document" I have tried to place the code in textview but still no luck I can not get the softkeyboard to show at all, its as if my code is being ignored..I have tried these two codes separately nothing works

```
<com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Keyboard
    android:keyWidth="%10p"
    android:keyHeight="50px"
    android:horizontalGap="2px"
    android:verticalGap="2px" >
   <Row android:keyWidth="32px" >
   <Key android:keyLabel="A" />
...
</Row>
...
</Keyboard>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please put your code in a linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView

android:id="@+id/keyboard"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Keyboard
android:keyWidth="%10p"
android:keyHeight="50px"
android:horizontalGap="2px"
android:verticalGap="2px" >
<Row android:keyWidth="32px" >
<Key android:keyLabel="A" />
...
</Row>
...
</Keyboard>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a `layout` as it behaves like a base foundation for your UI. All you need to do is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Keyboard
    android:keyWidth="%10p"
    android:keyHeight="50px"
    android:horizontalGap="2px"
    android:verticalGap="2px" >
   <Row android:keyWidth="32px" >
   <Key android:keyLabel="A" />
...
</Row>
...
</Keyboard>

    </LinearLayout>
```

OR

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Keyboard
    android:keyWidth="%10p"
    android:keyHeight="50px"
    android:horizontalGap="2px"
    android:verticalGap="2px" >
   <Row android:keyWidth="32px" >
   <Key android:keyLabel="A" />
...
</Row>
...
</Keyboard>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

`Linear Layout` and `Relative Layout` are the most widely used layouts in android UI. You can find the tutorial for `Linear Layout`  from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) and the tutorial for `Relative Layout` from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).

Hope this helps.