# Android units of measurement: %{number}p syntax

Tags: android, units-of-measurement

```
<Keyboard 
  android:keyWidth="%10p"
  android:keyHeight="50px"
  android:horizontalGap="2px" 
  android:verticalGap="2px">
```

What does `%10p` mean? I couldn't quite find it in the documentation or on Google. I'm assuming it's 10% of keyboard width?

Answer (score 0):

10p is percent:

> May be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended
>   with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp
>   (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred
>   font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).
>
> May be a fractional value, which is a floating point number appended
>   with either % or %p, such as "14.5%". The % suffix always means a
>   percentage of the base size; the optional %p suffix provides a size
>   relative to some parent container.
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol keyWidth.

[Source.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html)

Comment: and % as prefix? exmamples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232871/android-custom-keyboard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987788/no-xml-content-please-add-a-root-view-or-layout-to-your-document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html or did they all just copy the wrong example from the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

> May be a fractional value, which is a floating point number appended
>   with either % or %p, such as "14.5%". The % suffix always means a
>   percentage of the base size; the optional %p suffix provides a size
>   relative to some parent container.

The Android keyboard layout is based on rows and each row has keys. The `{number}%p` is the width of the keys in the keyboard unless it is explicitly defined on individual key. The `{number}%p` means the width of key in percentage relative to parent container.